# IHP: ./start: line 29: RunDevServer: command not found

Tags: haskell, ihp

when execute the ./start of the blog example, got the following error:

**error: cycle detected in build of '/nix/store/mhgprkxfnmjglp547skvagf4kwikd23h-ormolu-0.1.4.1.drv' in the references of output 'bin' from output 'out'**

cannot go further, seek help!

Comment: Are you running on Apple? apparently there is a [problem/bug](https://github.com/digitallyinduced/ihp/issues/1273) running `IHP` on M1 chips. On The github thread they say that you should run on x86 emulation mode.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.